# Random stratified sampling with different proportions

Tags: r, random

I am trying to split a dataset in 80/20 - training and testing sets.  I am trying to split by location, which is a factor with 4 levels, however each level has not been sampled equally. Out of 1892 samples -

Location1: 172
Location2: 615
Location3: 603
Location4: 502

I am trying to split the whole dataset 80/20, as mentioned above, but I also want each location to be split 80/20 so that I get an even proportion from each location in the training and testing set.  I've seen one post about this using `stratified` function from the `splitstackshape` package but it doesn't seem to want to split my factors up.

Here is a simplified reproducible example -

`x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 9, 7, 1, 5, 6)`
`xx <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D")`
`df <- data.frame(x, xx)`
`validIndex <- stratified(df, "xx", size=16/nrow(df))`
`valid <- df[-validIndex,]`
`train <- df[validIndex,]`

where `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` correspond to the factors in the approximate proportions as the actual dataset (~ 10, 32, 32, and 26%, respectively)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if your initial dataset is RANDOMLY split 80/20 then you expect each location to be split 80/20. Just because you do it in a random way.

Comment: The `caret` package also has a few functions for splitting data: http://topepo.github.io/caret/splitting.html

Comment: @AntoniosK Even if the proportions of the dataset are not even?  I figured it would just randomly take 80% without considering the proportions - maybe I am wrong though

Comment: That's the whole point of randomisation. A random sample should reflect (approximate) the patterns of the population. The only problem you might have is a factor with a very small proportion not being picked. Imagine a class with 8 boys and 2 girls (10 students) and pick 5 random. There's a chance not to pick any girl. The stratification would ensure that you'll pick 1 girl and 4 boys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bothSets` should return you a list containing the split of the original data frame into validation and training set (whose union should be the original data frame):

```
splt <- stratified(df, "xx", size=16/nrow(df), replace=FALSE, bothSets=TRUE)
valid <- splt[[1]]
train <- splt[[2]]

## check
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",splt))
all.equal(df[with(df, order(xx, x)), ],
          df2[with(df2, order(xx, x)), ],
          check.names=FALSE)
```